# How to properly source dependencies using git?

Tags: git

The project I'm working on has some dependencies. Should I put the dependencies in my repo? Or should I just list them? Is there a convention to sourcing dependencies?

Comment: what do you mean by sourcing? If its another git repo maybe `git submodule` would do what you want

Comment: What kind of project is this, .NET, Java, Ruby, PHP, etc? Depending on the technology, how you add dependencies to your project is likely to be different. Avoid adding 3rd-party binary dependencies and compiled code to your project, because Git is ill-suited for versioning binaries, since it has to keep a copy of every version every time they change, and thus causes your repo size to blow up and become unmanageable.

Comment: Was this ever answered to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 3):

If the your dependencies have Git repositories, you can use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to keep track of those projects.

Aside from that, you can specify dependencies and installation instructions in a README for you project or provide a script that will install the proper dependencies.